# how to display images url using hashmap

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashmap

[image]

how to apply the image to the coding  `map.put( "coverimage", cursor.getString( 3 ) );`  can appear as I should have tried repeatedly and did not get a solution. maybe the teacher here can help me deal with that.I have also toured various sites and have not yet found that answer

Comment: Post the code instead of posting images. you can use `map.get("coverimage")` to get the value of that Map.

Comment: tried it still can't Picasso.get().load( map.get( "coverimage"));

Comment: he image does not appear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value, you just call:

```
map.get("coverimage");
```

Comment: tried it still can't Picasso.get().load( map.get( "coverimage"));

Comment: he image does not appear

Comment: You should try hard coding the value and see if you're using the function properly. So instead of ```Picasso.get().load(map.get("coverimage"));``` do ```Picasso.get().load("url");```